# Configure "remote sharing" SSH interface on OS X Mojave

Tags: macos, sshd, macos-mojave

I use a VPN connection for work but I'd like to be able to SSH to my Mac while I'm connected to my VPN.

If the VPN is connected the "remote sharing" interface binds to the tun, not my wifi address (eg, it shows that I should ssh [user]@[tun-ip] not [user]@[wifi-ip]), and obviously I don't have access to the tun interface from my home network.

If I disconnect from the VPN the Remote Sharing interface is correct and I can SSH as appropriate.

Is there a way to configure which IP is allowed? I'm guessing it's a firewall or something since the /private/etc/ssh/sshd_config is configured to bind to 0.0.0.0.

I should note that this seems to be related to the Mojave upgrade - the same VPN client / network was used on El Cap and I could SSH direct to the WiFi interface when connected to the VPN.

Comment: Perhaps [sshuttle](https://github.com/apenwarr/sshuttle) will help ([link](https://www.devroom.io/2012/07/11/vpn-too-complicated-use-a-ip-over-ssh-tunnel-instead/)). Question: Can the problem be with some firewall?

Comment: My use case is wanting to SSH to my Mac from my device (I don't have a KVM setup at home and just need a terminal).

Comment: Is there a problem with using sshuttle?

Comment: sshuttle isn't ideal - my workflow is to develop using my Windows desktop by SSHing into my OS X system with a DynamicForward setup so that I can access my work resources and PUTTy/WSL for a terminal client. IIUC sshuttle would only work for this if I could SSH direct from OS X to an SSHd on my Windows host, plus I would not be able to get the terminal access. I'd be better off just ssh'ing out from my OS X system with a RemoteForward of my OS X SSHd to some other host that I control and can access from Windows.

Comment: Is your problem similar to the one [solved here](https://filipmolcik.com/pptp-vpn-on-macos-sierra-and-high-sierra/)? Otherwise, perhaps [iSSTP](https://github.com/axot/isstp) could help ([discussion](https://disqus.com/home/discussion/axot/isstp_8211_a_sstp_client_for_mac_osx/oldest/)).

Comment: Grab netcat and attempt to listen on the OS X machine, port 22, on wifi interface. Can you then connect to this port 22 from the Windows desktop via telnet/nc? If you can't connect, I'd suggest once you are connected to the VPN it is routing traffic destined for the local net (e.g. 192.168.0.0) our the VPN gateway or you have a firewalling issue. If you can connect to the netcat session, then I'd suggest you look in /etc/ssh/sshd_config to verify if you have a ListenAddress or something else that would restrict the interface on which SSH listens.